# ClassNotFoundException when running WildFly Swarm Arquillian test

Tags: java, jboss-arquillian, wildfly-swarm

(Referenced by https://issues.jboss.org/projects/SWARM/issues/SWARM-767)

I am trying to test my WildFly Swarm application using Arquillian. I have a custom `Main` class for my Swarm, and a custom deployment. When I attempt to run my tests, I receive a ClassNotFoundException on some third party libraries from maven.

First of all, here is my test:

```
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class PasswordStorageTest {

    @CreateSwarm
    public static Swarm createSwarm() {
        return TestBuilder.createSwarm();
    }

    @Deployment
    public static WARArchive createDeployment() {
        return TestBuilder.createDeployment();
    }

    @Test
    public void testHashesAreUnique() throws PasswordStorage.CannotPerformOperationException {
        String password = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        String hash1 = PasswordStorage.createHash(password);
        String hash2 = PasswordStorage.createHash(password);

        assertNotEquals("Hashes were not unique.", hash1, hash2);
    }

    @Test
    public void testVerifyPassword() throws PasswordStorage.CannotPerformOperationException, PasswordStorage.InvalidHashException {
        String password = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        String hash = PasswordStorage.createHash(password);

        assertTrue("Password verification failed.", PasswordStorage.verifyPassword(password, hash));
    }

}
```

`TestBuilder.createSwarm()` and `TestBuilder.createDeployment()` simply call these methods, respectively:

```
public static Swarm buildSwarm() throws Exception {
    Swarm swarm = new Swarm();
    //Configure PostgreSQLDS
    swarm.fraction(new DatasourcesFraction()
            .jdbcDriver("org.postgresql", (d) -> {
                d.driverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
                d.xaDatasourceClass("org.postgresql.xa.PGXADataSource");
                d.driverModuleName("org.postgresql");
            })
            .dataSource("PostgreSQLDS", (ds) -> {
                ds.driverName("org.postgresql");
                ds.connectionUrl(System.getenv("JDBC_DATABASE_URL"));
                ds.userName(System.getenv("JDBC_DATABASE_USERNAME"));
                ds.password(System.getenv("JDBC_DATABASE_PASSWORD"));
            })
    );
    //Enable Infinispan Caching
    swarm.fraction(InfinispanFraction.createDefaultFraction());
    //Set Default Datasource
    swarm.fraction(new JPAFraction()
            .defaultDatasource("java:jboss/datasources/PostgreSQLDS"));
    return swarm;
}

public static WARArchive buildDeployment() throws Exception {
    WARArchive deployment = ShrinkWrap.create(WARArchive.class);
    deployment.addModule("org.postgresql");
    //Add all classes
    deployment.addPackages(true, "com.example.myapp");
    //Add all resources
    recursiveAddAsClassesResource(deployment, RESOURCES);
    //Add all web files
    recursiveAddAsWebResource(deployment, WEB);
    //Add all Maven dependencies
    deployment.addAllDependencies();
    return deployment;
}
```

When I run the test, WildFly Swarm starts up just fine, but as soon as the deployment is deployed, I receive this error:

```
2016-10-10 18:31:03,841 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-7) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."a0fdd090-cd55-4063-be86-23f6331f73f0.war".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."a0fdd090-cd55-4063-be86-23f6331f73f0.war".POST_MODULE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment "a0fdd090-cd55-4063-be86-23f6331f73f0.war"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:154)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: WFLYSRV0177: Error getting reflective information for class com.example.myapp.core.domain.services.FileService with ClassLoader ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.a0fdd090-cd55-4063-be86-23f6331f73f0.war:main" from Service Module Loader
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentReflectionIndex.getClassIndex(DeploymentReflectionIndex.java:70)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.metadata.MethodAnnotationAggregator.runtimeAnnotationInformation(MethodAnnotationAggregator.java:57)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.handleAnnotations(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:106)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.processComponentConfig(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:91)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.deploy(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:76)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:147)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/coobird/thumbnailator/geometry/Position
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2583)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1916)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.ClassReflectionIndex.<init>(ClassReflectionIndex.java:72)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentReflectionIndex.getClassIndex(DeploymentReflectionIndex.java:66)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.coobird.thumbnailator.geometry.Position from [Module "deployment.a0fdd090-cd55-4063-be86-23f6331f73f0.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:198)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:363)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:351)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:93)
    ... 15 more
```

I removed the code that references `net/coobird/thumbnailator/geometry/Position`, and then got a similar error with a different library. It seems like the libraries are just not being included at all.

Possibly related, I also receive a ton of these messages on deployment start: (However, they appear even when running the app normally, and cause no problems as the app loads perfectly fine)

```
WFLYSRV0059: Class Path entry file:/C:/Users/mitch/.m2/repository/net/coobird/thumbnailator/0.4.8/thumbnailator-0.4.8.jar in /C:/a0fdd090-cd55-4063-be86-23f6331f73f0.war/WEB-INF/lib/classpath.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
WFLYSRV0059: Class Path entry file:/C:/Users/mitch/.m2/repository/com/sparkpost/sparkpost-lib/0.16.1/sparkpost-lib-0.16.1.jar in /C:/a0fdd090-cd55-4063-be86-23f6331f73f0.war/WEB-INF/lib/classpath.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
```

This is confusing me, especially because if I set `testable = false` on `@Deployment`, then it runs perfectly fine; however, since the test is now running outside the container, I can't use CDI injections, which I need.

I can provide any more info needed. I don't know where to go from here.

Comment: I can't see anything obviously wrong that would cause a problem.

Will take a look in our next Sprint